# Startup (and services) profiles in Windows

Tags: windows, boot

I'm trying to find a solution that would allow me to setup different startup profiles for Windows 7 and Windows 2008.

The idea is be able to boot (or reboot) Windows with a custom set of startup applications and services for different usage. E.g. A fast profile with minimal programs and services; a development profile with SQL Server, MySQL, IIS, Dropbox and SVN etc. etc.

It would be nice if I could choose the profile after booting.. so maybe a fast boot with minimal startup applications/services and then a profile choice that would then load up the required profile.

Comment: Seeing as there aren't really any suggestions for existing app solutions... Is there a way that I could manually dump serivces/startup items into text files that I could then selectively feed lists of into a bat script to start them up after a clean boot?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Startup Manager Project](http://startupmanager.org/). Maybe it doesn't completelly solve your problem but is a good reference to begin:

> As the name suggests, Startup Manager (aka st-m) is an open source
>   startup manager for the Windows platform.
>
> Startup Manager can:
>
> - Make programs start on logon (add items)
> - Rename existing items
> - Delete existing items
> - Disable existing items
> - Enable existing items
> - Create a batch file with programs that start in a certain order
>
> Startup Manager supports:
>
> - Startup folders (all users and current user)
> - Registry sections
>
>   - All the run and services sections (all and current user)
>   - Computer sections: winlogon (userinit and shell) and BHO (browser helper objects)
> - Win.ini sections (load and run)

[image]

Comment: It seems to only deal with startup items, while equally as important to me are the services that are started (or not).
Otherwise, looks like a useful application. Especially like the creation of bat files for manual startup of items. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: FYI, I seem to be facing permissions problems with Startup Manager under Windows 7 x64, even if I run it as an Administrator.